# How do I gather and store variables from multiple sheets using a for each loop and display them in a cell on a different sheet in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, list, for-loop

I'm trying to pull values from a variable number of sheets within a single excel file using VBA. After I pull these values, I want to display them on a separate sheet in a column. I have very little VBA experience, so I used a little bit of python in my code to show what I'm working towards. Thank you!

This is what I've been working on. (OVERALL is the name of the sheet I want to store the list in):

```
Sub vba_loop_sheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim list_of_values

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        list_of_values.Extend (ws.Range("B1").Value)
    Next ws

    OVERALL.Range("B2").Value = list_of_values

End Sub
```

Comment: To collect the values you can use (eg) a `Collection` or an array. Alternative, just write each one directly to OVERALL.  Do you mean to place the names all in B2, or in a list/column beginning at B2?

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you so much for your help so far! I am trying to list them all in a column beginning at B2. I tried running the code in the most upvoted comment on this question by user VBasic2008, however, I got a "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" error. Can you help me to identify how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

### Copy the Same Cell Values From 'All' Worksheets to a Column

```vb
Sub SameCellToColumn()
    
    Const SRC_CELL As String = "B1"
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "B2"
    Const DST_SHEET As String = "Result"
    
    Dim Exceptions(): Exceptions = Array("Result", "Whatever")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To wb.Worksheets.Count, 1 To 1)
    ' Never mind if it's too big...
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet, dr As Long
    
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(sws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            dr = dr + 1
            dData(dr, 1) = sws.Range(SRC_CELL).Value
        End If
    Next sws
    
    If dr = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no worksheets found
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL)
     ' ... because we're using only 'dr' rows.
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(dr)
    
    drg.Value = dData

    MsgBox "Cell """ & SRC_CELL & """ values retrieved.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi VBasic2008, tank you so much for the help. I ran the above code, but got the following error: "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range". Can you help me to identify how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub vba_loop_sheets()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nextrow As Long
    
    nextrow = 2
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'check the sheet code name
        If ws.CodeName <> "OVERALL" Then
            OVERALL.Range("B" & nextrow) = ws.Range("B1")
            nextrow = nextrow + 1
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```